# Spring Beans Profiles and OSGI

Tags: java, spring, osgi, apache-servicemix

I've faced an issue during developing spring and `OSGi` based application. In my application I would like to use Spring `beans` profiles, however I don't know how to force use specific profile. I've used one time, spring profiles but in web application and I followed this tutorial: http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-31-environment-profiles.

But I don't know how to do this in OSGi environment, because I couldn't find some equivalent of `ApplicationContextInitializer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if spring-dm supports that, as its based on older Spring. Spring profiles was added to Spring 3.1, which was created long after spring-dm was a dead project.
http://www.springsource.org/osgi

Answer (score 0):

Spring-DM probably doesn't support newer versions of Spring, but [Eclipse Gemini Blueprint](http://eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/) does.  If you can use Spring 3.1.x or above and Blueprint, you can probably get Spring profiles working.  One way to do this would be to [extend the Blueprint Extender bundle](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/1.0.2.RELEASE/html/app-deploy.html#app-deploy%3aextender-configuration) with your own implementation of an `OsgiApplicationContextCreator` that configures the `ApplicationContext` `Environment` active profiles as you see fit.  For example, consider the following custom `BlueprintContainerCreator` implementation:

```
public class MyOsgiApplicationContextCreator extends BlueprintContainerCreator {
  @Override
  public DelegatedExecutionOsgiBundleApplicationContext createApplicationContext(
      BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    DelegatedExecutionOsgiBundleApplicationContext applicationContext = super
        .createApplicationContext(bundleContext);

    if (null == applicationContext) {
      // non-spring/blueprint bundles will not build an ApplicationContext
      return null;
    }

    // determine environment profile here...
    applicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("myProfile");

    return applicationContext;
  }
}
```

You would need to put this into a fragment bundle attached to the blueprint extender bundle.  Do the following:

You'll need to create a bundle with three files in it: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, META-INF/spring/extender/extender.xml (the xml file could be named anything with an xml extension, but must be in the META-INF/spring/extender folder), and your `OsgiApplicationContextCreator` implementation. Your MANIFEST.MF file will need to contain the OSGi manifest header Fragment-Host of `org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender`. If you're using the maven-bundle-plugin, your plugin configuration would look something like this:

```
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.5</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <Fragment-Host>org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender</Fragment-Host>
      <Export-Package>your.package,!*</Export-Package>
      <Import-Package>org.osgi.framework,org.springframework.core.env,!*</Import-Package>
    </instructions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Your extender.xml file will need to define your custom`OsgiApplicationContextCreator` bean with a name of `applicationContextCreator`. The file may look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
  <util:properties id="extenderProperties">
    <prop key="shutdown.wait.time">30000</prop>
  </util:properties>
  <bean id="applicationContextCreator" class="your.package.MyOsgiApplicationContextCreator"/>
</beans>
```

Then deploy the bundle into your environment. You may need to restart the Blueprint OSGi bundles (or your server) depending on the order this fragment bundle is installed in relation to the Blueprint bundles.